# Stop storyboard when BackgroundWorker finished

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, backgroundworker

When Method ExportStarts() is called, I want to start an animation. Then I call another method within the logic unit (Manager.StartExport()), where I do stuff using a Background Worker. When it finished, I want to go back to the View and stop the animation. How can I do that?

View.xaml.cs

```
if (...)
{
 storyboard.Begin();                 
 List<TaskResult> Results = manager.StartExport();
 storyboard.Stop();
}
```

manager.StartExport()

```
public static List<TaskResult> StartExport()
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_Do);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        return Results;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already answered your own question, didn't you? You got everything you need.....

Answer (score 0):

You want stop storyboard after worker_RunCompleted yes?

Check [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

If I understood correctly - this will be helpful.

`_storyboard.Stop();` raises after setting the result of  `_storyboardTaskCompletionSource` in `RunWorkerCompleted`.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _storyboardTaskCompletionSource;
Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();

private async Task InitAsync()
{
    _storyboardTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    _storyboard.Begin();

    StartProgress();

    await _storyboardTaskCompletionSource.Task;

    _storyboard.Stop();
}

public void StartProgress()
{
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _storyboardTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //logic
}
```